# Odd and even numbers with single filter?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have recently faced an interview question where I was required to filter out odd and even numbers from a `List`. The only catch was that **I could not use 2 filters** like the following:

```
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
        
List<Integer> odd = nums.stream().filter(n -> n%2 != 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
List<Integer> even = nums.stream().filter(n -> n%2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I said it was not possible since the final `collect` method can **only return 1 single list.**

What am I missing?

Comment: You can use a grouping or a partitioning collector for it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> response = nums.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(n -> n % 2 == 0));
```

This will return :

```
{false=[1, 3, 5], true=[2, 4]}
```

to separate them you can use:

```
List<Integer> evens = response.get(true);
List<Integer> odds = response.get(false);
```

Comment: GM Sir. Time for another Q review? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66329361/how-to-avoid-code-duplication-in-gradle-configuration-code ?

Comment: This way can also work :
nums.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(num->num%2==0?"EVEN":"ODD")); 
Produce the output as : {EVEN=[2, 4], ODD=[1, 3, 5]}