# How to avoid code duplication in gradle configuration code?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

From my toplevel gradle.build.kts:

```
allprojects {  
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri(
                "https://" +
                        getGradleProperty("artifactory-url-prefix") +
                        ".artifactory....whatever/foo/"
            )

            credentials() {
                username = getGradleProperty("id")
                password = getGradleProperty("apikey")
            }
        }

        maven {
            url = uri(
                    "https://" +
                            getGradleProperty("artifactory-url-prefix") +
                            ".artifactory....whatever/bar/"
            )

            credentials() {
                username = getGradleProperty("id")
                password = getGradleProperty("apikey")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is plenty of code duplication. I see how I could create a helper method to do build the URL, but is there a canonical/idiomatic way to "do" the `credentials()` block just "once"?

Comment: The build script is just Groovy code. You can use what you would normally use in Groovy to avoid duplication.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Then s/Groovy/Kotlin/g

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610815/refactor-maven-block-in-gradle

Comment: is `artifactUrls` what you are after? e.g. `maven { url = uri(...); artifacturls("..../bar", "..../foo"); credentials { ...}}`

Comment: @Roland Looking at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:maven_repo ... this is probably not helping here. That function is used when one has additional JARs on the repo server, which is not what we need.

Comment: @MartinZeitler that looks like Groovy.  This is Kotlin.

Comment: @RyanM giving ideas is often a good starting point ... and most groovy can easily be brought to kotlin.

Comment: That's fair.  Someone (probably not Martin) voted to close it as a duplicate, which it's not.  But Martin's link is indeed relevant.

Comment: Yeah, just clicked the wrong button on that, though. But overall, the content there and here should bring future readers to a reasonable outcome.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good use for an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html):

```
// At top of file

import org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository

// Anywhere in file

fun MavenArtifactRepository.addCredentialsToRepository() {
    credentials {
        username = getGradleProperty("id")
        password = getGradleProperty("apikey")
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
allprojects {  
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri(
                "https://" +
                        getGradleProperty("artifactory-url-prefix") +
                        ".artifactory....whatever/foo/"
            )

            addCredentialsToRepository()
        }

        maven {
            url = uri(
                    "https://" +
                            getGradleProperty("artifactory-url-prefix") +
                            ".artifactory....whatever/bar/"
            )

            addCredentialsToRepository()
        }
    }
}
```